# Searchkick filtering by buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I have a 'feed' model, which has_many entries, these are all displayed on one page. Searchkick is all set-up and works like a charm with a default search bar, but unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to do it with buttons instead.

I'm trying to use Searchkick to search via button clicks (Click Colour Brandy, get all results which match colour Brandy etc). I see in it's documentation this is called 'Aggregation', an example of this would be { color: "brandy" }.

Would I have to create individual methods for each of the filters within my controller/model? Then call them with a button click? How would I go about handling multiple?

Comment: Are you sending the search parameters with an ajax request? Can you share your search bar code so we can see how it needs to be modified?

Comment: I'm actually just trying to build simple buttons similar to a filter on a clothing website. e.g. Click 'Size M' it filters for Medium clothes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't add new actions to your controller. Expanding on that aggregation example from Searchkick's doc:

> in the controller

```
def filters
  allowed_filters = %w(color size)
  filters = params.select{|k, v| allowed_filters.include?(k) }
end
helper_method :filters
```

> in the view

```
= link_to 'color brandy', {action: 'index', filters.merge(color: 'brandy'}, class: 'ui-button'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but how would I go about adding this into the view etc?

Comment: View? Why that? Those few lines go into the controller.

Ah, I see the buttons. In that case make the `filters` a method in your controller. I'll put the code here, comments here don't do linebreaks: https://gist.github.com/TomK32/6ef879faec9e999cd41a8948b9f3cdaf

Comment: Hi Thomas, can you edit the answer just so it helps everyone :) I guess the view button can be copied and pasted to make other filters.

Comment: good idea, copied the answer over here. yes, just copy to add more buttons. and the `filters.merge({...})` will keep the previous buttons filters